# Attempt to call private method + conflict with the .rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am Facing a weird error. Can any one explain me the reason for this..

I have a model called Site, Settings and Experiences.

Settings and Experiences has database column " **bit** "

In my site model, I have this code

```
  def populate_experiences_bit_set
    self.experiences.map(&:bit).inject(0, :|)
  end

  def populate_settings_bit_set
    self.settings.map(&:bit).inject(0, :|)
  end
```

In my rake file called 2_28.rake there is method called **bit**

```
 def bit(klass)
    current_class = klass.find(:all)
    if current_class.count == 0
      return 1
    else
      return (current_class.last.bit * 2)
    end
  end
```

This method is used in one of the rake task 'get_value' in the same rake file.

Also another rake task called create_sites_report_data in the same file which has a line :

```
site.populate_experiences_bit_set
```

Now when i run rake task

```
rake releases:2.28:create_sites_report_data
```

I get an error stating

> " Attempt to call private method
>   /Users/rakeshshetty/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:236:in
>   `method_missing' "

```
In console, this works fine 

>> s = Site/364
=> #<Site id: 364, name: "1 Field Ambulance - Detachment Wainwright", type: "Site", created_at: "2009-12-29 16:53:58", updated_at: "2009-12-29 16:53:58", short_name: "1 Field Am", self_updated_at: nil, last_updater_id: nil, vfp_id: "2BL0NFMI1", dup_reference_id: nil, field_id: nil, marked_as_deleted: false>
>> s.experiences.map(&:bit).inject(0, :|)
=> 0
>> s.settings.map(&:bit).inject(0, :|)
=> 64
```

I replaced the method name in my 2_28.rake file from bit to bit_x
Rake worked fine

```
blsi1181a:cpi_2.24 rakeshshetty$ rails -v 
Rails 2.3.5 
blsi1181a:cpi_2.24 rakeshshetty$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

My question is bit is a field in Settings and Experience. How does it call rake method function bit() ?
Is this rake file loaded after the application is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem:

The model has not a `bit` method, it creates it with a "method missing" approach (that is, when you call a not existent method on an object, it calls its method_missing method, which raises an exception by default).

ActiveRecord uses method missing in order to set methods of the columns of the related tables (that is:

```
Site.new.bit -> the method does not exist -> method_missing -> 
  is there a column called 'bit'? -> yes -> create the method bit with this code
```

Now, you created a `bit` method at Object level. Probably it breaks the `method_missing` approach of ActiveRecord:

```
Site.new.bit -> the method exists -> call that method
```

Resources:

- [BasicObject#method_missing](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/BasicObject/method_missing)
- [ActiveRecord::Base#method_missing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.5/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L232)

---

## EDIT: AFTER A DEEPER ANALYSIS

If you look at ActiveRecord source (near the error):

```
def method_missing(method_id, *args, &block)
  method_name = method_id.to_s

  if self.class.private_method_defined?(method_name)
    raise NoMethodError.new("Attempt to call private method", method_name, args)
  end

  [...]
```

Now, try this tasks:

```
namespace :rake_test do

  desc 'With bit method'
  task :with => :environment do

    def bit(klass)
      # Implementation
    end

    puts Object.private_method_defined?("bit")
    puts Settings.private_method_defined?("bit")

  end

  desc 'Without bit method'
  task :without => :environment do

    puts Object.private_method_defined?("bit")
    puts Settings.private_method_defined?("bit")

  end

end
```

Let's run them:

```
rake rake_test:with ; rake rake_test:without
```

The output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

When you define the `bit` method, you are in the Object context (this is true not just for the rake tasks files, but for every ruby script file). So you define an `Object.bit` method; as you can see from the Rails source code, before to define the model `bit` method it tries to see if there is a `Model.method`, and, if there is, it raise an exception.

Being the `Settings` class subclass of `Object` (like every standard class), your `bit` definition breaks the thing.

Comment: But y does it take the method from .rake file?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more details. Please do explain

Comment: I made a deeper analysis. If you are wondering "why does Rails try to see if Settings has private a method called bit?`, I let you know that I'm asking myself it too :)